# Gradle/Maven Java WebApp + Bower as separate modules in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, web-applications, intellij-idea, bower, dependency-management

I am working in a University project which involves developing a Java-based JSF WebApp. For the development I will be using IntelliJ IDEA and Maven or Gradle (at this point I don't care which one, any of them will fit).

I will also be using JavaScript in the project and I would like to manage its dependencies with Bower.

I could easily throw a js folder inside the webapp directory. I have seen many examples of this, but I do not like it as an approach.

What I want to do is separate the server side implementation from the UI implementation. So, I guess that means having two modules in IntelliJ IDEA, one containing all the Java-based server implementation and another one containing the static web files.

How can I accomplish this using IntelliJ IDEA and/or WebStorm if necessary? Actually, can it be done? Any suggestions welcome/appreciated.